# dynamic number of where clause conditions in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am trying to search a data table for all the entries that have any of a list of words. The list can have a variable number of words. Here is my code right now:

```
string[] Words = InitialString.Split(' ');

                foreach (string word in diseaseWords)
                {
                    List<mrconso_SnoMed2014> curMatches = (from a in masterDB.mrconso_SnoMed2014s
                                                        where a.STR.ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower().Trim())
                                                        select a).ToList();
                    matches.AddRange(curMatches);
                }
```

This code is taking too long to execute. All of the database calls are taking time. I would like to use some dynamic query that has a variable number of where clauses. Something like:

```
List<mrconso_SnoMed2014> curMatches = (from a in masterDB.mrconso_SnoMed2014s
                                                            where a.STR.ToLower().Contains(Words[0].ToLower().Trim())
                                                            or a.STR.ToLower().Contains(Words[1].ToLower().Trim())
                                                            ...
                                                            select a).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Intersect from LINQ, looks something like:

```
list1.Select(s=>s.STR.ToLower).Intersect(list2.Select(s=>s.ToLower().Trim()))
```